# How to fetch [] from Jarray which has value {[]}

Tags: json, json.net

I have a Restapi which in certain conditions returns empty response like below. response format is Json

```
"value": []
```

I able to get this in Jarray

```
JObject joResponse = JObject.Parse(Response.Content);
JArray array = (JArray)joResponse["value"];
```

This array has value {[]} .
I need to get this [] so that I can further assert this .

```
Assert.True(responseContentValue.Equals("[]"));
```

test case says we need to have empty brackets [] returned .

Comment: You can just do `Assert.True(array != null && array.Count == 0);`.  Why do you need to assert that the re-serialized JSON string for the array is `[]`?

Comment: will not work , I need to fetch [] as value

Comment: Why not?  You want to assert that the array is empty so checking the count does exactly that.  Anyway you can do `Assert.True("[]".Equals(responseContentValue?.ToString()));` -- i.e. `ToString()` re-serializes the `JArray`.

Comment: 'test case says we need to have empty brackets [] returned .' - believe it is supposed to convey array is empty, which is what you need to test. This can be done as @dbc mentioned. The '[]' in here is not a string literal in json. It conveys empty array